# Formatting String to "dd/MM/yy"

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I have a string which needs converting to "dd/MM/yy". I am converting it to a Date datatype and then formatting it back to a string. I was wondering if there is an easier/elegant way of doing it.
Here is an example of how I am achieving this now

```
Dim strValue As String = "17/08/2016"
Dim dteValue as Date = Convert.ToDateTime(strValue)
strValue = dteValue.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

What I am looking for is a way of converting without casting it to a Date datatype, is it possible?

Comment: Is the input format always `dd/MM/yyyy`? You could just snip out the `yy` of the string if it is.

Comment: What you are doing looks good, another way is to simply remove the 3rd last and 4th last character from the given string, using any string operation.

Comment: If you start with a `String` and you end with a `String` and you don't convert to a `Date` in between then it's just text like any other.  Just like any text, you can perform string manipulation operations on it.  For instance, you could call `String.Split`, `String.Substring` and then `String.Join`.  That's not exactly any easier or more elegant though.  Also, the code you have is going to fail if the culture is set to something that doesn't use "dd/MM/yyyy" as the short date format, e.g. en-US.  It might be worth your while to use `Date.ParseExact` or `.TryParseExact`.

Comment: @RemarkLima,  yeah I could do that but the next stage is a range where the string is "From Date: 17/01/2016 To Date: 17/08/2016" which is where it gets a bit complicated

Comment: @AmanSinghal as per my previous comment, I cannot count characters in it :-(

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I have used this `Date.ParseExact(strDatatableValue, "dd/MM/yy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)` but getting an error "String was not recognised as a valid DateTime".

Comment: If you need to treat the data as dates then you should be storing it as `Date` values, not `String` values.  Do the initial conversion and then leave it in that form.  You can then just convert to a `String` in the required format for display purposes as and when you need to.  All use of the data as data gets done with `Date` values. Man, if I had a $ for every time a beginner tries to make their life more difficult by using a `String` instead of a `Date`, I'd be a rich man by now.

Comment: "getting an error "String was not recognised as a valid DateTime""  Of course you're getting that error message.  Is the `String` in that format?  No it isn't, so why would you think that would work?  Your input text is in format "dd/MM/yyyy" so obviously that is the format you have to provide to `ParseExact` if you want it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121160/discussion-between-leprechaun-and-jmcilhinney).

Comment: Why don't you get it in the desired format from the input?

Comment: If you can't count characters then what you're doing is fine... You could make it nicer with an extension method.

Comment: @wonderbell I dont deal with the input, it is only given to me, so haven't got a say.

Comment: @RemarkLima, Thanks!

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is debatable about your $ rich man comment. Agreed that it is far too common.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static string ToMyDateString(this string stringDate)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(stringDate).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
string strValue = "17/08/2016".ToMyDateString();
```

or

```
string strValue = "17/08/2016";
string strValueDate = strValue.ToMyDateString();
```

Just realised you're in VB.NET so pretty sure it'll translate over. If I get a moment I'll try and do it in VB.NET.

**VB.NET version**

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function ToMyDateString(stringDate As String) As String
    Return DateTime.Parse(stringDate).ToString("dd/MM/yy")
End Function
```

Warning - this has just been put through a converter, so may need to be tweaked.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is essentially the same logic I used but twisted slightly. Im afraid it is not what I am looking for, I wanted to know if it is possible to convert without changing the datatype. Turns out it is not. I understand my approach may not be correct but it is what it is and I need to work with it.

Comment: Ah, but you asked for a more elegant way, and extension methods are very elegant in my opinion, just call them onto the type and you're set!

Comment: If you read my question carefully especially the last line "is there a way of achieving this without the datatype casting". Not questioning your code "Elegance" at all.

Comment: Absolutely, but you can't manipulate the string directly, so you have to cast to a date... And then you're left with "how to make it look more pretty" ;)

Comment: What I had in mind was when you use Val("some string") it gives you the number, is there anything like that for the date? OR anything in regex.

Comment: Just write your own `DateVal` method surely? `Val("some string")` will be converting the string to a number internally, and returning that number so is just a method already built.

Answer (score 0):

Without casting it to Date I would suggest:

```
        Dim strValue As String = "17/08/2016"
        strValue = strValue.PadLeft(6) & strValue.PadRight(2)
```

It takes my computer 1 ms to process above code 10.000 times, but 22 ms to process yours.

Edit: if the date has different lengths, you could split on the forwardslash and rebuilt it:

```
        Dim arrSplitValue() As String = Split("17/08/2016", "/")
        Dim strValue As String = arrSplitValue(0) & "/" & arrSplitValue(1) & "/" & arrSplitValue(2).PadRight(2)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I posted in my comments counting characters defeats the purpose as the string may be different lengths.

Comment: Sorry, my point seems to be unclear, the date string can be "17/08/2016" or "From Date: 17/08/2016" or "xyz", so counting characters in strings and padding approach is not going to work in this case. Thanks for your help!